# how to know if a set of arbitrary vectors are a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

So, if we're given that $\{x,y,z,w\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^4$, how do we show that $\{x+w, y+w, z+w, w\}$ is also a basis of $\Bbb R^4$?

I know that for a set to  be a basis, it has to be linearly independent and it also has to span a subspace (I need clarification on this).

What I did was $a(x+w) + b(y+w) + c(z+w) + d(w) = 0$ where $a=b=c=d=0$ for linear independence but i'm not sure if I can finish it from there let alone if what I did was even correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you the example in $\Bbb R^3$, and you can extend this to your case.

> Suppose $\{x,y,z\}$ is a basis. Prove that $\{2x, y+x+z, z+2y\}$ is also a basis.

Suppose $a,b,c$ are constants such that $a(2x)+b(y+x+z)+c(z+2y)=0$, now this is just 
$$
(2a+b)x+(b+c)y+(b+2c)z=0
$$

As $\{x,y,z\}$ is a basis, then $2a+b=0, b+c=0, b+2c=0$. Solving this systems yields $a=b=c=0$, as the dimension of $\Bbb R^3 $ is $3$, and we've got a linear independent set of $3$ vectors, this is a basis.

Answer (score 0):

I'll change the naming somewhat, as using the names used in the question would make this hard to read.

If $(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$ is a basis of a $4$-dimensional vector space$~V$ (it might be that $V=\Bbb R^4$, but knowing that details would only be confusing here), then every $v\in V$ can be uniquely written as $v=x_1v_1+x_2v_2+x_3v_3+x_4v_4$ for $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\in\Bbb R$. Moreover, the map $f:V\to\Bbb R^4$ that sends such a vector $v$ to $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, in other words which gives the *coordindates* of $v$ relative to that bases, is an isomorphism of vector spaces (obviously the map $\Bbb R^4\to V$ that is given by $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\mapsto x_1v_1+x_2v_2+x_3v_3+x_4v_4$ is its inverse).

Now you can use that another list of vectors is a basis if and only if their images by $f$ form a basis of $\Bbb R^4$. In you concrete example the list consists of $w_1=x_1+x_4$, $w_2=x_2+x_4$, $w_3=x_3+x_4$ and $w_4=x_4$ and their images are $f(w_1)=(1,0,0,1)$, $f(w_2)=(0,1,0,1)$, $f(w_3)=(0,0,1,1)$, and $f(w_4)=(0,0,0,1)$. I trust you know how to show that those concrete vectors form a basis of$~\Bbb R^4$.